# Show hide keyboard is not working propery in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

i follow this link to use the keyboard event by using [Simon mac donald Defination][1] In that event i show my footer when keyboard hide and hide my footer when keyboard is show.when click the **dictonary** my keybord is **show** but the event is goes to keyboard **hide** function(so my footer is shown)  ..i dont know why..

i attached my code and design .Kindly solve this issue

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () 
    {
        document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", onHide, false);
        document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", onShow, false);

    });
    function onHide() 
    {
        $("#footer").show();
    }

    function onShow() 
    {
        $("#footer").hide();
    }
    </script>
<style type="text/css">

#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:7%;
    background-color:#00458D;
    padding:0;
    border-width:3px;
    padding-top:3%;
    padding-bottom:2%;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    background-color:#00458D;
}

#content {
    position:absolute; bottom:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
  </head>
 <body >
    <div id="content">

        <input type="text" style="width=70%">
            <br/>
            <br/>

        <div id="footer" align="center">
            <table width=100%>
                <input type="image" src="../images/Home.PNG" style="width:23%" onClick="home()"/>
                <input type="image" src="../images/messages-menu.jpg" style="width:23%" onClick="inbox()"/>
                <input type="image" src="../images/settings-menu.jpg" style="width:23%" onClick="settings()"/>
                <input type="image" src="../images/close-menu.png" style="width:23%" onClick="callServiceFunction()"/>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

images

Comment: I checked... This works absolutely Fine.... Infact you are using it in a wrong way

Comment: Thank you for replying Coder,,,,Whats my wrong kindly guide me..its working fine but when i click the dictionary my footer comes up why...its go to keybord hide function but my keyboard is shown

Comment: when i click the space bar and when i click the dictionary its not working properly in my Tab(samsung Galaxy tab 2.0)

Comment: You are testing it on Samsung galaxy Tab 2.0?

Comment: ya am testing Samsung galaxy tab and android version 2.0

Comment: So my solution didn't worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.ready()` function and add the listeners in the deviceready

```
<style type="text/css">

#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:7%;
    background-color:#00458D;
    padding:0;
    border-width:3px;
    padding-top:3%;
    padding-bottom:2%;
    padding-right:0px;
    padding-left:0px;
    background-color:#00458D;
}

#content {
    position:absolute; bottom:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    overflow:auto;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);

    function onDeviceReady () {
        document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", onHide, false);
        document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", onShow, false);

    }
    function onHide() 
    {
        $("#footer").show();
    }

    function onShow() 
    {
        $("#footer").hide();
    }
    </script>

  </head>
 <body >
    <div id="content">

        <input type="text" style="width=70%">
            <br/>
            <br/>

        <div id="footer" align="center">
            <table width=100%>
                <input type="image" src="../images/Home.PNG" style="width:23%" onClick="home()"/>
                <input type="image" src="../images/messages-menu.jpg" style="width:23%" onClick="inbox()"/>
                <input type="image" src="../images/settings-menu.jpg" style="width:23%" onClick="settings()"/>
                <input type="image" src="../images/close-menu.png" style="width:23%" onClick="callServiceFunction()"/>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hmmm i see there is a bug here

Answer (score 0):

Try it in OndeviceReady ()

```
 $(document).ready(function () 
 {
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 }
 function onDeviceReady()
 {

     document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", onHide, false);
     document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", onShow, false);

 }
 function onHide() 
 {
       $("#footer").show();
 }
 function onShow() 
 {
       $("#footer").hide();
 }
```