# jQuery Mobile selectmenu focus and blur event won't fire

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am trying to hide a footer when a  form element is given focus.  I also want to show a footer when a  form element loses focus, which the blur event should handle.  I can't get the focus or blur event to fire on a jQuery Mobile selectmenu  form element.

Here is an example of one of my  form elements -

```
<select id="radiology-study-provider" class="selectList"></select>
```

Here is the jQuery code that is supposed to hide my footer on focus and show it on blur (it is inside DOM ready) -

```
  $('.selectList').change(function(){
      console.log("the change event is firing");
  });
  $('.selectList').focus(function(){
      $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').hide(); // hide the footer
  });
  $('.selectList').blur(function(){
      $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').show(); // show the footer
  });
```

It is strange that the change event handler fires but focus and blur will not.

I have tried this below and it won't work -

```
  $('.selectList').on('focus', function(){
      $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').hide(); // hide the footer
  });
  $('.selectList').on('blur', function(){
      $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').show(); // show the footer
  });
```

I also tried this -

```
   $('.selectList').bind( "focus", function(event, ui) {
       $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').hide(); // hide the footer
  });
   $('.selectList').bind( "blur", function(event, ui) {
       $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').hide(); // hide the footer
  });
```

I also tried the focusin() and focusout() events with no luck either.  I tried dozens of selectors (div.ui-select was one of them).  I don't think it is an issue with the selector I am using.

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.1.0 and jQuery 1.7.1 - I have checked the jQuery Mobile selectmenu documentation at http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/selects/events.html, talked to the google, searched here, and can't find this issue out.

Comment: Hey mate, does your change method `$('.selectList').change` work at least?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady () {
    document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", onKeyboardHide, false);
    document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", onKeyboardShow, false);

}

function onKeyboardHide() {
    $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').show(); // show the footer
}

function onKeyboardShow() {
    $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').hide(); // hide the footer
}
```

I came across this here on stack - [Show hide keyboard is not working propery in android phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686368/show-hide-keyboard-is-not-working-propery-in-android-phonegap) and noticed there are those 2 events you can listen for.

Answer (score 1):

Try commenting out the focus event and try.. Sometimes when the focus event fires it is fired multiple times because of which you don't see the code that is executed...

```
$('.selectList').change(function(){
      alert("the change event is firing");
  });

 // $('.selectList').focus(function(){
 //    $('div:jqmData(role="footer")').hide(); // hide the footer
 //    alert("Focus event is firing");
 // });

  $('.selectList').blur(function(){
      //$('div:jqmData(role="footer")').show(); // show the footer
      alert("Blur event is firing");
  });​
```

I commented out the focus event and the other two events seem to fire..
Remove the comments and you see the focus event getting fired multiple times..

Check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/C3veS/)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately the blur event won't fire.  I need to somehow know when the android keyboard is present and this is possible by the focus and blur event handlers on form elements.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me using the following example:

**JS:**

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){}, false);

    $(function() {
        $('.selectList').change(function(){
            console.log("the change event is firing");                                      
        });

        $('.selectList').focus(function(){
            console.log("FOCUS");
            $('#my_footer').hide(); // hide the footer
        });

        $('.selectList').focusout(function(){
            console.log("FOCUS OUT");
            $('#my_footer').show(); // show the footer
        });
    });
</script>
```

where `#my_footer` is the id of my footer (check the HTML below).

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="content">

            <select id="radiology-study-provider" class="selectList">
                <option value="1">A</option>
                <option value="2">B</option>
                <option value="3">C</option> 
            </select>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

You may have a try at this example and see if this works for you mate :S

Hope this helps. Let me know about your results.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  Once again though, only the change event wanted to fire.  I figured out a solution though, I'm going to post what worked for me.

Comment: Your welcome mate :). I'm curious to see what was the problem :S... I'll be waiting for your solution :P

Comment: I gotta wait 5 more hours to self-answer because I have less than 10 reputation.  I'll post it up here tomorrow.  Thank you again.