# Phonegap + Android 4.4: How to detect when the SoftKeyBoard hides?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I tried to add a event listener to detect when the softkeyboard hides, but it doesn't work!

I tried this code:

```
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {           
       document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", function() {
           alert('hidekeyboard!');
       }, false);
    }, false);
```

I tried to detect it while a input losses the focus, but when the soft keyboard hides, the input element still remains the focus..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just tested with phonegap 3.4.0 & android 4.4.2 in an emulator & the  same code you have used, and it works. are your other deviceready events getting fired? I mean are you sure everything else is working fine apart from the hidekeyboard event listener.

Comment: I created a clean new page with this one code an it still is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. The problem was that the 'hidekeyboard' event was never triggered by Phonegap due to the fact that the webview had errors and was static (it never resizes when the softkeyboard was triggered). As the webview never resizes, the event never is triggered.

We can find the triggering of the event in the class LinearLayoutSoftKeyboardDetect.

Thanks to all!

Comment: That was the answer, seems to be a bug and the dimensions don't change in Phonegap side when on keyboard opening or closing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
    var lastFocused;

    $(document).on("focusout","input[type='date'],input[type='time'],input[type='week'],input[type='text'],textarea,select",function(){
        lastFocused = undefined;
        // console.log("yes me call focusout");
    });

    $(document).on("focus","input[type='date'],input[type='time'],input[type='week'],input[type='text'],textarea,select",function(){

        if(utils.isUndefined(lastFocused) == false && lastFocused.is($(this)) == false){
            lastFocused.blur();
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            // console.log("Here you can get your keyboard is hide");
        }

        lastFocused = $(this);
        // console.log("yes me call focus");

    });
```